# _input not called for a node inside a Viewport

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a scene with two viewports, the "root" viewport and another inside it, like this:

```
Root
- SomeNode1
- SomeNode2
- RootCamera
- Viewport
  - SomeDeeperNode1
  - ViewportCamera
```

Now, I have a script attached to a node that belongs to the `Viewport` node, and it works otherwise, but its `_input()` method is not called. The script itself works because if I move it out of `Viewport` (so that it's under `Root` node) it works fine. Is there something that should be taken into consideration for the `_input()` method to be invoked when it's located inside another viewport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `Viewport` to get input, it must be inside a `ViewportContainer`. Thus, if you want the inner `Viewport` to receive input, you must put it inside a new  `ViewportContainer` (it can have no size, or be invisible, input should still work).

The alternative is, of course, to manipulate the `Viewport` from an script located elsewhere where it can get input.

By the way, if you enable `gui_disable_input` your `Viewport` will not get input, nor anything inside of it.