# How to make a collision object within a viewport detect mouse inputs?

Tags: 3d, godot, mouse, viewport, gdscript

I am working on a 2D game with a spatial node (a 3d node) inside a viewport.
Nodes within the viewport should be able to detect user input from what I can find online, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work for me.

My tree holds the viewport in a viewportcontainer. The node within the viewport handles the effects of detection. In a standalone scene, the node detects mouse inputs without any problems.

[image: Order of nodes within the viewportcontainer]

The code of the spatial script:

```
extends Spatial

func _on_Area_input_event(camera, event, position, normal, shape_idx):
    if (event is InputEventMouseButton):
        print(get_parent().name)
```

Furthermore, I made sure that:

- `Handle Input Locally` within the viewport is `true`
- `Disable Input` in Gui within the viewport is `false`
- `Object Picking` in the viewport is `false`
- The viewport container is not blocked by any other nodes

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct for `_input`. I have covered it in [another answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/194711/10408).

Turns out that the requirement for `_input_event` (and the `"input_event"` signal) are different:

- Set `gui_disable_input` ("Disable Input" in "Gui") to false.
- Set `physics_object_picking` ("Object Picking" in "Physics") to true.

---

You also want to make sure that any `Control` that overlaps the area you are interested in has `mouse_filter` ("Filter" in "Mouse") set to "Ignore". Including the `ViewportContainer` itself. This is because `Control`s will take priority (even if the `Control` is behind what you are trying to interact with).

Comment: I tried setting Object Picking to true. I also made sure that the node is not obscured by any other control nodes. Unfortunately, it hasn't worked

Comment: @Qusk2 To reiterate that `Control`s take priority, even if they are behind. And it can be the `ViewportContainer` itself. Which is why I'm telling you to change `mouse_filter`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was able to forward the input events to the viewport in an attached script like this:
(The reference to the viewport may need to be adjusted)

```
func _input(event):
    var viewport : Viewport = get_child(0)
    viewport.physics_object_picking = true;
    viewport.unhandled_input(event)
```

The script must be added to the viewport.
`physics_object_picking` must be `true`.
It doesn't work with `_unhandled_input`. The forwarding must be done in the `_input` function.

See also: [this confirmed error report](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/17326).